# 'Command' object has no attribute 'CommandNotFound'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

*I'm trying to send a message when a user sends an unknown command, but I'm getting this error.
**Same happened** when I tried to make a message sent if a command was sent on cooldown, but I gave up and **scraped that code**. But now I really want to know what I am doing **wrong**!*

**How I import the discord modules:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

**This is the error handler:**

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Command not found, silly.", description=f"Please use existing commands. {ctx.author.mention}", color=0xd93600)
        embed.set_footer(text="Guessity.")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**Error:**

```
if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'CommandNotFound'
```

Thanks.

Comment: @FierySpectre Well, I get another error. ```AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'errors'.``` Edit: I put wrong error, sorry.

Comment: @FierySpectre Sorry, I put wrong error above, I've fixed that.

Comment: @FierySpectre No, `commands.errors.[ErrorName`] is aliased to `commands.[ErrorName]` to make code shorter. You don't have to add `.errors`, it doesn't make a difference. The issue for his code is elsewhere.

Comment: @stijndcl yeah i realised that after i went through the code of discord.py now, my bad... As i said i havent messed with it :sweat_smile: (oh i wish that'd actually give the emote). I'll delete my previous comment to not mislead anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue using search function.

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    print("error: ",error)
    if search("not found", str(error)):
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Command not found, silly.", description=f"Please use existing commands. {ctx.author.mention}", color=0xd93600)
        embed.set_footer(text="Guessity.")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        raise error
```